# What is the difference between affect and effect?

Tags: differences

Does anyone know the difference between affect and effect? The definitions I have found online are confusing and I don't understand them. If someone could define it that would be great!

Comment: Please elaborate on what in particular you find confusing about the definitions you've found, because otherwise the answers you get here are unlikely to resolve the confusion.

Comment: This is actually a good question; the duplicate is maybe not the best. I have up-voted to cancel out your down-vote losses. You need to spend some time on this and do some research.

Comment: Please quote all the definitions that you've consulted, and explain for each of them why you find it confusing. Only then can people answer this question without running the risk of duplicating word-for-word some or all of the definitions you've already dismissed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases:

> Affect is usually a verb, and it means to impact or change something.
>
> Effect is usually a noun, and is the result of a change.  Its the thing the affect changes...

So, if A affects B, B experiences the effect of A’s action.

However, an exception:

*Effect* as a verb means to bring about. It is usually used with nouns like “change” or “solutions”, for example:

"*The protesters wanted to effect change in the corrupt government.*" . That is, they want to bring about the effect - change.

There are probably others..